# Why slug function leaves a - at the end of title if there is any symbol?

Tags: php, slug

heyya all,

my slug function is working but i am having an issue.

say if i write some title for article e.g. The fox is very cunning why?

now because i added ? the end of title i get a - e.g. the-fox-is-very-cunning-why-

here is my function

```
function slug( $string, $separator = '-' )
{
    $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
    $special_cases = array( '&' => 'and', '@' => 'at', '%' => 'percent', "'" => '');
    $string = mb_strtolower( trim( $string ), 'UTF-8' );
    $string = str_replace( array_keys($special_cases), array_values( $special_cases), $string );
    $string = preg_replace( $accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) );
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Can someone help fix please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
```

In this line, you are replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with the separator, and `?` is not an alphanumeric character, so it is replaced, and you do nothing to remove it later.

You can add a `$string = trim($string, $separator);` at the end of the function to remove trailing `$separator` characters at the end of the string.